# SQL Multiplication query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm trying to do a multiplication sum but can't seem to find out why it's not working. 
I've found the amount of days, but now need to multiply this by the daily charge.

Can anyone help?

```
SELECT `Daily_Charge`, DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date) AS `Total`, 
`Total`*Daily_Charge AS `Done` FROM `Car`,`Contract` WHERE `Contract_Id`="1";
```

Comment: What don't you have a join condition between Car and Contract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use alias names only in later clauses of a query and not in the select clause itself. Use

```
SELECT `Daily_Charge`,
        DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date) AS `Total`, 
        DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date) * Daily_Charge AS `Done`
FROM `Car`,`Contract`
WHERE `Contract_Id`='1';
```

Comment: Thanks, Was almost there :P

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an column alias in another column definition, you need to write the formula again:

```
SELECT `Daily_Charge`, DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date) AS `Total`, 
       DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date)*Daily_Charge AS `Done` 
FROM `Car`,`Contract` 
WHERE `Contract_Id`="1"
```

Alternatively, you could do the formulas in a subquery, and use those columns in the calculations, like:

```
SELECT `Daily_Charge`, `Total`,  `Total`*Daily_Charge AS `Done` 
FROM (SELECT `Daily_Charge`, DATEDIFF(End_Date,Start_Date) AS `Total`, 
      FROM `Car`,`Contract` 
      WHERE `Contract_Id`="1") as Source
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL - Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in **GROUP BY**, **ORDER BY**, or **HAVING** clauses to refer to the column:
>   ...
>   Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a **WHERE** clause. This restriction is imposed because when the **WHERE** clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.
>   ...

As others already noted, just duplicate the [`datediff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) formula.